# Conditional replacement of row's values in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, performance, pandas

This is my pandas DataFrame:

```
ID  START   END  SEQ
1   11      12   5
1   14      15   6 
1   13      14   7 
2   10      14   1
3   11      15   1
3   16      17   2
```

I want to change the values of SEQ so that for the same ID the SEQ values would be 1, 2,... etc., e.g.

```
ID  START   END  SEQ
1   11      12   1
1   14      15   3 
1   13      14   2 
2   10      14   1
3   11      15   1
3   16      17   2
```

How can I do it efficiently avoiding for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a tiny bit to Boud's answer, if what you intend is to have the order in resulting SEQ column depend on the value of the START column, you can achieve this through

```
df['SEQ'] = df.sort_values(by='START').groupby('ID').cumcount()+1
```

That is,

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   ID  START  END  SEQ
0   1     11   12    5
1   1     14   15    6
2   1     13   14    7
3   2     10   14    1
4   3     11   15    1
5   3     16   17    2

In [4]: df['SEQ'] = df.sort_values(by='START').groupby('ID').cumcount()+1

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   ID  START  END  SEQ
0   1     11   12    1
1   1     14   15    3
2   1     13   14    2
3   2     10   14    1
4   3     11   15    1
5   3     16   17    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cumcount on a groupby operation:

```
df.groupby('ID').cumcount()+1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches with `NumPy` using [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) to create those *ramp* arrays -

```
def id_ramp(a):
    out = np.ones(a.size,dtype=int)
    idx = np.nonzero(np.append(True,a[1:] > a[:-1]))[0]
    out[idx[1:]] = -idx[1:] + idx[:-1] + 1
    return out.cumsum()

def id_ramp2(a):
    out = np.ones(a.size,dtype=int)
    idx = np.nonzero(a[1:] > a[:-1])[0]+1
    out[idx[0]] = -idx[0]+1
    out[idx[1:]] = idx[:-1] - idx[1:]+1
    return out.cumsum()
```

Runtime test -

```
In [381]: a = np.sort(np.random.randint(1,100,(1000)))

In [382]: df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=[['ID']])

In [383]: %timeit df['SEQ'] = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()+1 #@Boud's soln
100 loops, best of 3: 2.01 ms per loop

In [384]: %timeit df['SEQ'] = id_ramp(df.ID.values)
1000 loops, best of 3: 315 µs per loop

In [385]: %timeit df['SEQ'] = id_ramp2(df.ID.values)
1000 loops, best of 3: 304 µs per loop
```

If you are working with `ID` column that is not always sorted, we need to use some `argsort` there, like so -

```
a = df.ID.values
sidx = a.argsort(kind='mergesort')
df['SEQ'] = id_ramp2(a[sidx])[sidx.argsort()]
```

Let's look at a sample case to see how it works -

```
In [447]: df
Out[447]: 
    ID
0    1
1    1
2    7
3    5
4    3
5    8
6    1
7    3
8    7
9    2
10   5
11   7

In [448]: a = df.ID.values
     ...: sidx = a.argsort(kind='mergesort')
     ...: df['SEQ'] = id_ramp2(a[sidx])[sidx.argsort()]
     ...: 

In [449]: df
Out[449]: 
    ID  SEQ
0    1    1
1    1    2
2    7    1
3    5    1
4    3    1
5    8    1
6    1    3
7    3    2
8    7    2
9    2    1
10   5    2
11   7    3
```